# jquery, fancybox in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, fancybox

I have an issue that I just cannot resolve.  I am loading an iframe instance of fancybox. the iframe contains an external link.  everything works great in all browsers, except IE.  seems to me that the frame source or parent is not inhering correctly or something, but I just cannot figure it out.

1. the link starts an instance of fancybox of iframe type
2. the page loads fine, its a form.
3. the form gets filled out and submitted, THEN!
4. the page does not accept the form submission (only in IE)

   ```
   <a href="https://www.agentcertification.com/Login/Login/82010bb0-107f-4432-934e-c88cbd12450d"     class="fancybox-iframe">link</a>

   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.fancybox-iframe').fancybox({
               width: 1280,
               height: 800,
               autoSize: true,
               autoResize: true,
               autoCenter: true,
               href: $(this).attr('href'),
               type: 'iframe',
               iframe: {
                    preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
               }
          });  
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your HTTPS page has non-secure HTTP content (mixed content) and fancybox is not able to display the IE's security warning therefore the form is not submitted.

You could disable the "Mixed Content" Warnings in IE. Read this for more

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx

Unfortunately this is directly related to particular IE settings so you can't control if your visitors have disable the security warnings or not in their IE. If not, your form will fail for them.

---

**EDIT** : this is what I get from your page in IE while loading it for the first time :

[image]

Comment: its makes sense, but can you explain why it works on chrome and other browsers.

Comment: @user2027317 : because most modern browsers still permit "Mixed Passive Content" in order to reduce [security warning fatigue](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsc-ui/#security-considerations-warning-fatigue).

Comment: I just tried that and no luck. still works on other browsers though.

Comment: also, it doesn't seem its a mixed content since, the page comes up. its after the form is submitted. TIA

Comment: Run [your page](https://www.agentcertification.com/Login/Login/82010bb0-107f-4432-934e-c88cbd12450d) in a new window in IE to see the mixed content security warnings

Comment: I did, there are no warnings at all.  it has more to do along the lines of jquery losing the document.domain attr in IE.

Comment: and I have verified that there is no mixed content.

Comment: @user2027317: see my edited answer and screenshot. If you are so sure that there is not mixed content, then you must figure out what the issue is then.

Comment: weird, I don't get that promp. but even so, it works in IE (without getting the promp) using a window and not in a fancybox iframe.